# How to squash commits when there are commits that do not belong with the current PR

Tags: git

If I do `git rebase -i HEAD~5`, I get

```
pick <hash1> CURR_PR
pick <hash2> PREV_PR_I_WORKED_ON
pick <hash3> WIP: another commit I want to squash in to CURR_PR
pick <hash4> WIP: yet another commit I want to squash in to CURR_PR
pick <hash5> WIP: and finally one more commit I want to squash in to CURR_PR
```

Typically I just replace all the `pick`s below `CURR_PR` with `s` and then change then clean up the commit message. However, for some reason, I have the commit with `<hash2>` in the way, and I do not want to squash in to that commit.

How can I squash commits with `hash3, hash4, hash5` in to commit with `hash1`?

Comment: if you're asking how to ignore that commit entirely then instead of `pick`, use the `drop` option for the `<hash2`> line, or simply remove that line  from the interactive rebase editor completely. if you're asking how to re-order your commits, use @Manuel Schmidt's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you want to keep changes of commit `<hash2>`, just move the line of `<hash2>` commit wherever you want to have it:

```
pick <hash1> CURR_PR
squash <hash3> WIP: another commit I want to squash in to CURR_PR
squash <hash4> WIP: yet another commit I want to squash in to CURR_PR
squash <hash5> WIP: and finally one more commit I want to squash in to CURR_PR
pick <hash2> PREV_PR_I_WORKED_ON
```

In this case you will have a single commit that squashes `<hash1>`, `<hash3>`, `hash4` and `<hash5>` and a commit containing the changes of `<hash2>`

In case you want to remove changes of commit `<squash2>` just remove the line.